# How to update Array without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i update array of users without refreshin page.
In database i have user
[image]

Im making request to take user data, and then i set user data into React Context.
Then i take profiles and map them on the page.

```
      {profiles === undefined || 0 ? "Loading..." :
         <>
          {profiles.map((user,id)=>
          <UserProfile key={id} name={user.name}/>
          )}
         </>
        }
```

[image]

When i post new profile in the user data, i need to refresh the page to see new account.

```
  const handleSudmitProfile = (e) =>{ // function to set new profile
    e.preventDefault();
    if(name.length === 0){
      setMessageError(true); // set error if input is empty
    }
    if(name){
    setNewUserForm(false);
    setMessageError(false);// clear error
    axios.post(reqApiUrl+"/createProfile",{name},{ withCredentials: true })
    .then((res)=>setUser(res.data))
    .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
    }
  }
```

[image]

This two popups on the one page, i just hide and show them.

Comment: I think you can implement a refetch function with axios and use it or you can use `react-query` package, it has this ability by default.
check here: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery

Comment: is the post request returning all the list or just the newly added one

Comment: it return just name of new one

Comment: You're looping over `profiles` which I assume is an array. When you get a response back from your `axios request` are you also adding the response to `profiles` and is it backed by state?